# getDefaultAdapter Zend framework 1.10

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

I have next settings in application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = some
resources.db.params.password = somepass
resources.db.params.dbname = name
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

have 2 similar models Zend_db_table_Abstract
in first model i use

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

all work fine 
but if i try use same in the second

i see next message

```
Exception information:

Message: No adapter for type Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
```

i tried to take adapter using another method but i see same Message

trying
in class extended zend_db_table_abstract

```
$this->getDefaultAdapter
```

Registry var db in Zend_registry from bootstrap

all time i see same message

Any idea ?

Comment: Do your Models extend any class?

Answer (score -2):

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$db->query('SET @rank:=0');
```

try this